# (Bukkit) (Java) Is there a way to spawn random mobs within a range, for example 32 blocks from the player with a little delay?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I want to make a way to summon mobs at a rando location within a range (32 blocks from the player location) every 5 seconds for example.
And if its possible, will it cause too much lagg?
And will it be always active?

Comment: Look at [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and [Scheduler Programming](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get their `Location` get their X and Z and increase by a random amount with a random, then spawn the mob. Make this in a new thread or in a bukkit runnable since otherwise yes it may cause lag (not sure about that part)

example code:

```
new Thread(() -> {

    int newX = p.getLocation().getX() + new Random().nextInt(32)+1;
    int newZ = p.getLocation().getZ() + new Random().nextInt(32)+1;
    int newY = /* find out the y value of the area */

    Location spawnLoc = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world_name"), newX, newY, newZ);

    spawnMob(spawnLoc);

}).start();
```

Comment: Ok, but there is a way to make this always run? Always with delay, obviously.

Comment: There's a problem, this code will spawn enity only in a direction, don't know why :(, do you know?

Comment: Yes, because he is only increasing X and Z, but you also want to decrease it sometimes. I would do it by doing this (for both): 'Player.getLocation().getX() - 32 + new Random().nextInt(64);'